# Why am I not able to use the push_back() function in the following c++ code?

Tags: c++, struct, stdvector

I'm trying to create a vector of structs - that I'll use later in other functions - for a structure called `customer`. However, when I use the `push_back()` function, I get the following error

> In template: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'customer'

Can anyone explain why I receive this error, please?

Here's the part of the code related to my problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct cartitem{
    //members of the struct
};

struct customer{
    string name;
    string arrival_time;
    float total_price = 0.0;
    vector<cartitem> cart;
    fstream mycart;
};

vector<customer> Customers;

static customer newCustomer(string cname, string arrtime){
    customer b;
    b.name = cname;
    b.arrival_time = arrtime;
    Customers.push_back(b);
    return b;
};
```

Comment: Customers is not static but newCustomer is. That's probably not what you want.

Comment: The real culprit is the `fstream` member. Streams are not copyable.

Comment: Do you want `newCustomer` to be creating a new customer, adding a copy of it to `Customers`, and then returning the one you just made? In any case an `fstream` is not copyable. It's not clear what you're doing with it so it's hard to say what changes should be made to `customer` and/or `newCustomer`

Answer (score 1):

When you call `push_back()`, you are pushing a **copy** of `b`.  However, `customer` has an `fstream` member, which does not support copying (only moving), so the compiler implicitly deletes `customer`'s copy constructor, which is what the `push_back()` is trying to call. That is why you get the error.

Comment: Note: `emplace_back(std::move(b))` can solve this (needs the `<utility>` header), but (in general) leaves the source (in this case `b`) in an undefined state due to "stealing" its resources, as opposed to copying them.

Comment: @CruzJean "*`emplace_back(std::move(b))` can solve this*" - so would `push_back(std::move(b))`, and `emplace({cname, arrtime})` (may need a constructor added).  "*but (in general) leaves the source (in this case `b`) in an undefined state*" - wrong. Proper moves must leave the source in a well-defined but *unspecified* state. That is different than being left in an *undefined* state. It is perfectly fine to setup a local variable and then move it elsewhere, provided the move operation is implemented correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any other way to "link" a file to a structure variable other than defining it as a member of that structure.

Comment: I tried push_back( std::move(b) ), it solved the problem but it didn't go well with the rest of the code. So I'm thinking of removing the fstream member but i need another way to link the mycart file to the objects of customer structure

Comment: @RemyLebeau I said in general. There is nothing stopping a move from leaving something in an undefined state. It need only guarantee that the destructor won't explode.

Answer (score 1):

As in Remy's post, push_back makes a copy.

Create a constructor and try:

```cpp
customer &newCustomer(const string &cname, const string &arrtime){
    return Customers.emplace_back(cname, arrtime); // requires C++17 or you can return Customers.back()
};
```

The example here should be useful: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back